# How to express properly "you cannot set this date field with a date that is 30 or more days in the past"?

Tags: expressions, time, dates

I need to place a validation message on a application which refers to the fact that a Hire Date cannot be set to a date that is older than 30 days, counting backwards from today. For example if today is the 1st of October, you could only set a date from the 1st of September or later.

Is this alright:

> You cannot set this date field with a date that is 30 or more days in the past

or what is the correct way to say it?

Comment: I would say "The date must be no earlier than 30 days from today", but something in my mind says that something is wrong with that! :). I am not sure; I am a learner

Comment: "The date entered/selected must be within the last 30 days." though your example is grammatically correct. Your question may be considered off-topic though, since there really isn't an English learning question, just how to write something. My example is just my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

A native speaker would understand:

> Hire Date must be *within the last thirty days*.

But if you have an international audience comprised of speakers with varying degrees of English competence, a more roundabout way might be better, since English learners often have trouble with prepositions like **within** and adjectives like **last**.

Comment: A whole _comprises_ its parts, while parts _compose_ a whole. Thus, an audience is _composed of_ speakers with varying degrees of English competence; or speakers with varying degrees of English competence _comprise_ the audience.

Comment: @P.E. Dant: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=audience+comprised+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Caudience%20comprised%20of%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Yes, mine is a voice in the wilderness.

Comment: @P.E. Dant : Ah, that would explain it. Wilderness is not comprised of. But land, farms, gardens, country are comprised of. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wilderness+comprised+of%2Cgarden+comprised+of%2Cfarm+comprised+of%2Cland+comprised+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgarden%20comprised%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfarm%20comprised%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cland%20comprised%20of%3B%2Cc0

Comment: TRomano: No, no, that's not it, at all. "A voice in the wilderness" is an idiom the meaning of which will be obvious, in this context, to native speakers.[link](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+voice+in+the+wilderness)

Comment: Obvious to an audience comprised of native speakers?

Comment: Obvious to those who do not worship at the Ngram altar, where, for instance, "ain't" magically becomes "is not." Obvious to those who understand why "Ten year anniversary" is redundant.

Comment: You don't have to take ngram at face value. If you check the citations on the ngram, you'll see that "comprised of" has a 200-year history and appears in a variety of texts.

Comment: I take it you have no truck with six-month anniversaries.

Comment: _Comprise_ is a useful verb with a specific meaning, just as is _Compose._ There have always been those who do not grasp their specific meanings or their utility, or the way in which they complement or oppose each other. My objective is to preserve as many specific and useful words as possible - in other words, to hold back the tide which seeks to replace every specific noun with "the thing" followed by its description, and every specific verb with "do" or "make" followed by a monosyllabic narrative. E.g., "the thing on the end of a shoelace" for "aglet." Ngram worship perpetuates the problem.

Comment: Have fun when you do that thing.

Answer (score 1):

> Hire date cannot be more than 30 days in the past.

If you're developing the app, you can help your user by displaying the actual date limit:

> Hire date must be June 12, 2016 or after.

Comment: Nice answer! I think a mix would be great: "Hire date cannot be more than 30 days in the past (07/12/2016 or after)"